# Convert String to Date error

Tags: java

I try to convert string to date format, but the following does't work.

```
    String stringdate = "Fri Mar 27 17:14:27 EET 2015";
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    try {
        Date newdate = format.parse(stringdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the output is

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Mar 27 17:14:27 EET
>   2015"

Comment: I dont see any issue with it even if i try to reproduce by running it.

Comment: this code is working here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is locale-sensitive, so your default locale may be the reason why the exception is thrown. Try setting the locale to US.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Is `Locale.US` aware of `EET` (East European Time)?

Comment: Yes but it is converted to CDT on my device (probably because I reside in the central time zone).